# What's your problem? in Japanese

Tags: expressions, slang

> -どうしましたか。
>
> -せきが出ます。

Apparently, this is a dialogue between a doctor and a patient. The doctor says, "**What is the problem?**" and the patient answers, "I have a cough."

How could we naturally say "**what is your problem?**" talking to a person who is acting strange? (What's your problem? - used for asking someone in a threatening way why they are behaving in a way that you do not like or approve of (Macmillan Dictionary)). For example:

> I have thrown away all the old photographs. - What's your problem? Those were my photos too!

Answer (score 3):

There is a phrase used to threaten in the context of a conflict. In media, you might hear people exchange with:

> どうした？文句｛もんく｝あるのか。

However, these are words that are exchanged when direct, maybe physical, conflict is bound to occur.

In the case of your example, I'm afraid that doesn't work as well. At least from my understanding, you can just skip over that and ask why they did that action with a very direct tone, and that will get the point across. Contrast these two reply examples:

> **Passive**
>
> でも僕の写真でもあったのに。
>   But those were also my pictures. (lit. There were also pictures of mine there)
>
> *raising a passive complaint*
>
> **Aggressive**
>
> どうして捨てたんだよ？！ 僕の写真でもあったぞ！
>   Why did you toss them?! Those pictures were also mine!
>
> *people generally avoid direct confrontation, so directly calling out an action already carries the feel of saying "What's your problem?" without saying it.*

You could really emphasize it by ending your sentence with some sort of emphatic remark like おかしいよ、君。 This remark might actually be the "What's your problem?" that you're looking for, but it doesn't mean that in a literal sense, however. The phrase does not translate well into Japanese.

EDIT: Thanks to Chocolate and l'électeur (as usual) for the assist.

Comment: +1, I think this is a good answer, and in particular I think the way 「おかしいよ」 or 「おかしいだろう」 is used to express that the other party's actions appear to be some combination of malicious and irrational corresponds pretty well to "What's your problem!?"

Comment: 「でも僕の写真もだったのに。」、「どうして捨てたのかよ？！ 」 and「 僕の写真もだったぞ！」.  None of these example sentences are either grammatical or natural-sounding, I am afraid.

Comment: @l'électeur I'm not sure what you mean. I'm avoiding saying その写真も僕のだった because it feels like I'm describing an item in a non-existent list, almost like saying in English "Those pictures are mine as well," without having said a first item i.e. like この写真は僕のです and その写真も僕のです however, I could be wrong.

Comment: @psosuna "Those were also my pictures" は、「僕の写真**でもあった** 」とは訳せますが、「僕の写真もだった」とは言えません。「～もだった」は、「私の写真はピンボケだった。」「僕の写真もだった。」(My picture was ~~, too.) って感じで使います。「どうして捨てたのかよ？」もおかしいです。「どうして捨てたんだよ？」ならいいです。「～か(よ)？」は、「捨てたのか(よ)？」(Did you~?) って感じで使います。

Comment: @Chocolate 教えてくれてありがとうございます！では、今すぐ答えを直します。

Answer (score 3):

> What's your problem? - used for asking someone in a threatening way why they are behaving in a way that you do not like or approve of.

I think you can say...

> 何か気に[入]{い}らないことでも あるの/あるわけ/あるのか？
>   何が 気に入らないの/気に入らないんだよ？
>   何か文句でも あるの/あるわけ/あるのか？
>   （いったい）なんなの / なんなんだよ！？
>   どういうつもり / なんのつもり（だよ）！？
>   何考えてんの / 何考えてんだよ！？
>   頭おかしいんじゃない の/のか！？

etc... depending on the context.

> I have thrown away all the old photographs. - What's your problem? Those were my photos too!

How about...

> 「古い写真全部捨てといたし。」
>   --「はぁ！？どういうつもり（だよ）！？自分だけのもんじゃ ないでしょ/ねーだろ！」

Comment: I feel like these are all a lot politer than the English version...

Comment: おぉ・・ そうなんですね・・・

Answer (score 0):

If you just mean the part "what is your problem" part of the photo disposal part, I guess:
 (assuming the person is acting delibaretly knowing the you don't want the photos to be destroyed, and he/she therefore doing it)
何（を）やってるの？
or (simply to state your "disapproval"):
いいかげにしろ！

Comment: 「いいかげ**ん**にしろ」ね・・